# Spring 3 validation not working

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I have a user entity in my application which I need to validate.

```
public class User {

private String userName;
private String password;

public void setUserName(String userName){
this.userName = userName;
}

public getUserName(){
return this.userName;
}   

// and so on
```

}

For this I have created a UsersValidator like below.

```
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
    return User.class.equals(clazz);
}

public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "userName", "field.required");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "field.required");
}
}
```

and I have a controller like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String home(@Valid User user,
        BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "loginForm";
    } else {
    //continue
}

}
```

The binding result does not have any errors.

What else I need to do in order for the validation to work? Do I have make any changes in the controller or the spring configuration file.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />

<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>com/dimex/resourceBundles/ApplicationResources</value>
            <value>com/dimex/resourceBundles/errors</value>
        </list>
    </property>            
  </bean>

<mvc:interceptors>  
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="locale"></property>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>
```

**EDIT:-**

Do I need to have hibernate validator in my classpath. We are not using hibernate in our application. 
Please help.

**EDIT2:-**

When I use validation annotations (@NotNull, @Size etc) directly in my entity class then @Valid annotations in controller works but if I remove them from my entities and try to use the validator written above then @Valid does  not work.

Is it like that @Valid annotations only work with the validation annotation in the entities only and not with the validators? In order to use my validators will I have to invoke the validate method in my validator directly?

Comment: Have you configured spring to instantiate the UserValidator? For example by annontating the validator with `@Component`? You can also achieve almost the same behavior if you annotate the fields on the bean with @NotNull.

Comment: @Augusto I have added @Component but still its not working !!!!!!

Comment: You also need `<context:component-scan/>` for `@Component`s to be picked up. Do you have this? Would be easier if you posted your Spring XML.

Comment: @matt b I have updated the question with the Spring xml.

Comment: If I explicitly do this.validator.validate(user, result); then its working but if I use @Valid then its not working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to combine [JSR-303](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) @Valid annotation with classic spring validation.  Why would you want to do this?  The equivalent JSR-303 annotations for `UserValidator` class would be something like below:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min=1)
private String userName;

@NotNull
@Size(min=1)
private String password

...
```

The spring [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation) illustrates the steps needed to configure JSR-303 validation. You would need `hibernate-validator` (or another JSR-303 provider) for the above to work.  You would also need to configure the `validator` bean as below.

```
<bean id="validator"
      class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
```

The other answers to this question are in the same line as well.

Comment: Isn't there a way to not use the Size annotation?

Comment: this was a ton of help for me!!adding `hibernate-validator`

Answer (score 11):

You need to define the validator to use in your controller using the @InitBinder annotation, for example:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(new UserValidator());
}
```

Comment: I think you need to annotate the @InitBinder with the name of the object you need validation.  For example @InitBinder("user").

Comment: Do you have Hibernate Validator on your path?

Comment: @Dave I dont have a Hibernate Validator on my path. Do I need one? I am not using Hibernate in my app

Comment: Yes, you need Hibernate Validator as this add the implementation for the @Valid tag.

Comment: Have you put Hibernate Validator on your path?  This is needed.

Answer (score 6):

Other way around is to call spring validator initialization from your controller

```
DataBinder dataBinder = new DataBinder(user);
dataBinder.setValidator(userValidator);
dataBinder.validate();

BindingResult result = dataBinder.getBindingResult();

if(result.hasErrors() == false) {
   // error exists
}
```

Comment: Is there a way I can use @Valid with validator classes?

Comment: I never used in that way. I use @Valid for model validations and initbinder for specific validations - frotnend, rest services and so own. You can check this thread here - http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?80077-Valid-binder.setValidator-and-other-fun

You will need to use initBinder annotation to get this working.

Comment: This manual approach works for me. But using the `@Valid` annotation on the model class doesn't trigger the validation for me, `BindingResult` shows 0 errors. Any hints?

Comment: `DataBinder` is an interface, how can you instantiate it like this   `new DataBinder(user)` ?

Comment: @SaurabhJ for reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `@Component` on the `Validator` implementation so that Spring container can recognize it as:

```
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {
```

and use following method in the controller:

@InitBinder(UserVO)
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {        binder.setValidator(userValidator);
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSR-303-style validation with Spring (i.e. a global Validator instance provided by a JSR-303 implementation, such as Hibernate Validator), **and** you have an `@InitBinder`-annotated method in your `Controller`, you **must** inject the `Validator` into your Controller **and** set it in the `@InitBinder` method:

```
@Autowired
public void setValidator(Validator validator) {
    this.validator = validator;
}

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(this.validator);
}
```

The `WebDataBinder`'s validator is by default set to `null`, not (as you would expect) to the global JSR-303 Validator instance, so your models won't be validated by Spring **unless you set the Validator instance** manually here.

This is only if you have an `@InitBinder` method. If you don't, everything works as expected.